# Running C++ executable files on Google-App-Engine - Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

My goal is to run a simple C++ Hello world program on google app engine via Docker deployment.

I'm doing this via terminal where i'm following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart#download_the_hello_world_app.

Also google does allow custom runtimes via: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes

### **Files in my directory:**

- Dockerfile
- app.yaml
- hello (cpp executable file that is compiled statically, not dynamically. Simply prints Hello, World!).

---

### Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.7
COPY . /
WORKDIR /
CMD ["./hello"]
```

### app.yaml

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

---

### Process

**First:** Ran the docker container via docker build -t hello . and it compiled and outputted the result:

> Hello, World!

**Second:** Since the docker container ran perfectly, I continued to move forward and ran the following:

> gcloud app deploy

---

### Error

After deploying, the project BUILDS, shows the docker container building, successfully tags it to the cloud and PUSH the repository and outputs DONE.

**The error I get is:**

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (cloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]
Application startup error:
Hello, World!
```

I viewed the logs online on google app engine and it shows textPayload: "Hello, World!" and other information but I'm confused, so did was this able to run successfully or am I missing something here? It shows it on the logs as shown below.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/18448620/46507626-4f37c900-c7ee-11e8-895a-8510cd46a691.png]

How would I resolve this issue? Also, it does not have to be app-engine, If there is a method to run this on Google Functions, that would be great also.

Thank You.

### Update

I went on the Google Cloud console where the project is built and viewed the build results, it shows the build was successful. Then I viewed the image that google cloud creates and pulled the image and ran it in the cloud shell browser as shown below.

Then I clicked the **Image** and did a **docker pull** and the output is shown below:

So does this mean this is actually working and being deployed on the cloud properly?

[image]
[image: Build output]

Comment: What exit value is your hello world program returning. Add the line `exit(0)` at the bottom of your `main` function.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hello John. When you say add an exit(0), are you saying    #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    exit(0);
} Because it outputted same error result as shown above in the original question. I've tried implementing this statically (locally) and then pushing it to container and building it statically within the container, I keep getting same error when I deploy it. Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: @JohnHanley Update: If I go on the Google-Cloud website and look at my deployment build, it shows the build successful. Then I viewed the pull command for the image google cloud creates, and I pulled the image in the cloud shell browser and ran the example and it outputted Hello World, does this mean this is working? I'll edit the post so you can view the images of what I am seeing.

Comment: I think that this is a runtime problem and not a build problem. Check what your program is returning and print it to your logs. https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html